# Error for REST API in nifi

Tags: rest, curl, apache-nifi

when i start Executestream prosessor  with src.bat  file  it shows me execution code 0 but it doesn't stop processor and  insede outputstream flowfile it shows  errors  like this:

```
  execution.error
    % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0 100 299 0 0 100 299 0 1472 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1472
```

I use commands  like this:

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary  "@C:\Users\user\Desktop\nifi-1.3.0\conf\stop.json" "http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/processors/ea5db028-015d-1000-5ad5-80fd006dda92"
```

and  json file  like this, what should i do?:

```
{
  "status": {
    "runStatus": "STOPPED"
  },
  "component": {
    "state": "STOPPED",
    "id": "f511a6a1-015d-1000-970e-969eac1e6fc5"
  },
  "id": "f511a6a1-015d-1000-970e-969eac1e6fc5",
  "revision": {
    "version": 30,
    "clientId": "0343f0b9-015e-1000-7cd8-570f8953ec11"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that if curl is reporting progress then somehow the output/process is reporting strangely to NiFi. Perhaps try the "silent" option for your curl command (see the documentation for how to enable that, often it's the -s flag)